# Is IE8 ready for corporate enviroment?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8

I am an IT-Admin at an medium sized lawyer firm.
I see that Windows Update is trying to push IE8 out to the market.

Does anyone know if there is any disadvantages to upgrade to IE8? Besides, perhaps, more memory usage compared to IE7.

The clients are running IE6 or IE7 currently, and none of the application are directly dependent on internet explorer as such.

Comment: "Besides, perhaps, more memory usage compared to windows 7."  Assuming you mean IE7 here, why are you assuming the new version of IE uses more memory?

Comment: That was a stupid typo. Thanks and corrected! Well, I have just never really met an application which new version had a smaller memory footprint. The few that does, usually brag a LOT about it - and I haven't heard such things about IE8

Comment: subject should be "for corporate environment", right? not enough rep to do anything about it....

Comment: @CarolinaJay65: done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Please don't upgrade Internet Explorer 6. Look at this site:* http://www.saveie6.com/

Jokes aside, Internet Explorer 8 works very well for me. I installed it on many computers and all the web applications still work without problems. Don't forget: there is always the IE7 compatibilty mode, if you have intranet applications which have problems with IE8.

Comment: I did not know of this feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've been running IE7 and IE8 since their early betas (which weren't very stable), and I can assure you that as long as your internal web apps work fine under IE7 then you will 
have no problems with IE8.

Also, as a web developer, anything that you can do to upgrade from IE6 would be a tremendous help.